# If $f$ is a nondecreasing function on $[a,b]$..

Tags: real-analysis, integration

If $f$ is a non-decreasing function on $[a,b]$ and $P$ is a partition of $n$ subintervals, find an expression for $U(f,P)-L(f,P)$.

I know that the end result has to be that $U(f,P)-L(f,P)=(f(b)-f(a))\left(\frac{b-a}{n}\right)$, I just don't know how to go about getting there.

Comment: Do all your intervals have the same width?  Is $U(f)$ the maximum value of $f$ on that subinterval? or is it the maximum value times the width of the interval?  It will help to define your notation.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  If you partition is $a=i_1 < i_2 < i_3 < ... < i_n=b$ then for the interval $[i_j, i_{j+1}]$ you know that the max value (on that interval) is $f(i_{j+1})$ and the min value (on that interval) is $f(i_{j})$.  When you start adding these up over all the intervals (consecutive ones) you'll get some cancellation...